# Logic behind a cubic reflection

Tags: shaders, camera, rotation, webgl, orbit

I'm creating a cube in WebGL made of mirros that have to reflect the object inside of it.

At the moment I'm stuck because I don't understand the correct logic to implement to achieve the result.
I tried put a camera in every face of the cube in order to have a cubemap to apply. The problems come when I try to rotate the cube: I'm not able to make the cameras follow the rotation.

What's the correct logic to implement?

These images could give the idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the only problem you experience, is making the cameras follow the cube's rotation, have you tried creating a parent-child relationship between them, in such a way that if the give is transformed in any way, the cameras will follow?

Comment: @TomTsagk yeah a sort of. I used the rotationMatrix of the cube to rotate the cameras... but after some rotations (in all axis) the result become weird. But the question is: is it correct my approach?